# Django Use values in static files

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have some standard colors set in my `settings.py`

```
colors = [
    ("blue", "#4a3ed0"),
    ("green", "#4ad041")
    # And some more
]
```

I load my static files using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'defaults/default.css' %}">
```

And I want to access green in my `default.css`. I made a template tag (named utils):

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_settings_color(color):
    for c in settings.colors:
        if c[0] == color:
            return c[1]
```

In my `default.css` I tried to access `get_settings_color` but it didn't work.

defaults.css:

```
{% load utils %}
div.green{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: {{ get_settings_color:"green" }}
    /* And some other fields */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a css file since the {% %} and {{ }} are django's template tags (html).

What you can do is:

In your html file, in the  add a  tag and reference them there, like so:

```
<style>
    div.green {
        color: #fff
        background-color: {{ get_settings_color:"green"}}
    }
</style>
```